# Using maple to calculate a value for mod computation

Tags: encryption, rsa, maple

I am working on some security stuff and am trying to implement a basic form of RSA encryption. I am working with Maple to compute some values, but I am struggle with being able to compute this:

These are the values I have: e, p, q

I need to compute which value for 'd' will work in the following equation:

```
d*e ≡ 1 mod (p-1)*(q-1)
```

Notation note: If a - b is a multiple of the number c, we write "a ≡ b mod c".

I was told I could use some sort of Power(a,b) mod c functionality in Maple, but I am not sure how to do it. Shed any light on how I can calculate the a value for 'd' in Maple? In my case, e = 65537, and both p and q are really large prime numbers (100+ digits each).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as `d:= 1/e mod (p-1)*(q-1);`

Answer (score 1):

You need the `gcdex` function, compute `s` and `t` such that `s*e + t*(p-1)*(q-1) = 1` and use `d=s`.

I feel bad not pointing this out: If this has anything at all to do with actual security (as opposed to learning about the theory), do **not** write your own code without spending a lot of time reading about attacks on implementations (as opposed to the math). RSA is very simple (and beautiful) mathematically, but surprisingly tricky to implement securely.

Note that there is a special StackExchange site for security, which you may be interested in.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with actual security :).

Isn't there a method I could use to calculate the modular inverse, since I know every value other than d?

Comment: As I said, `gcdex` will do that for you.